# Skip some columns from JMeter-jtl output file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

Till now, I've used JMeter 3.x versions to execute my SQLs.

Recently I've moved to JMeter 4.0. It's returning jtl with some additional columns like [datatype, sentBytes and grpThreads]. 
I'm loading the jtl to DB and I don't want to change the schema so I want to remove those additional columns in jtl file.

Is there any way to mute the additional columns to return in jtl file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `user.properties` you can add the following properties that control `datatype`, `sentBytes` and `grpThreads`:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false
```

In Configuration of a Listener (as `View Results Tree`)

Uncheck `Save Data Type`, `Save sent byte count` and `Save Active Thread Counts`

[image]